# How To Move Two Decimal Places To The Left On Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using google sheets to calculate sales tax for items our company is selling, but when I try and get the total sales tax, it produces it into a large number.

For example, I'm selling an item for $89.26, at a tax rate of 10.25%. The total should be 9.14915, and if it's rounded - would be 9.15

But the total that pops up at the moment is 915.

I'd like to know how to get the desired 9.15 and not 915

If anyone can help that would be great,

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that your "10.25" is being entered as exactly that. So your amount is 100X more than it should be. Even if you formatted 10.25 to have a percentage symbol after it, it may not actually be .1025 in memory (which is what it needs to be). If you'd like to share a link to your spreadsheet, being specific about where one should look to see your tax cell(s), we can take a look and explain how to address the issue. OR you can try typing 10.25% (including the percentage symbol) into the tax cell; or you can try typing .1025 into the tax cell (the actual decimal equivalent of 10.25%).

Answer (score 1):

multiply it by 0.01

```
=your_formula_here()*0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can divide by 100

```
=YOURFORMULA()/100
```